# What is the meaning of each part of this luminoth command?

Tags: conv-neural-network, gcloud

I am trying to train on a dataset using luminosity. However, as my computer has a poor GPU I am planning to use glcoud. It seems that luminoth has gcloud integration according to the doc(https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/luminoth/latest/luminoth.pdf).

Here is what I have done.

1. Create a Google Cloud project.
2. Install Google Cloud SDK on your machine.
3. gcloud auth login
4. Enable the following APIs:
   • Compute Engine
   • Cloud Machine Learning Engine
   • Google Cloud Storage
   I did it through the webconsole.

Now here is where I am stuck. 
5. Upload your dataset’s TFRecord files to a Cloud Storage bucket:
 the command for this is;

```
gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M cp -r /path/to/dataset/˓→tfrecords gs://your_bucket/path
```

I have the tfrecords file in my local drive and the data that I need to train on. However, I am not sure what each command in gsutil is trying to say. For /path/to/dataset/ do I simply input the directory my data is in? And I have uploaded the files to a bucket. Do I simply provide the path for it?

Additionally, I am currently getting

```
does not have permission to access project (or it may not exist)
```

Apologies if this may be a stupid question.